# How to use strings, integers, and float

Tags: string, integer

In what situations should you use strings, integers, and float in python. plus when I should change my type when in between the parenthesis. Last what does it do when I add a certain name like string, integers, and float to the line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, you might want to use `strings` of things that contain mixed characters or alphabets, like names, addresses, let's say some character constants, (though you should use enums for that, but it is not what you aksed).

Then for `int` type, they should be used in places where a integral value is required, such as counters, indexes, and maybe phone numbers if you want (for that some languages use `long int` though), but if you don't want arithmetic on your phone numbers, better stick with `strings` for them. Anything you want to operate on using `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` use `int`, and not `string`

Lastly, when you want more precision than integers, like when keeping things like salaries, or account balances, thing like Rupees and Paise, or Dollar and cents become equally important. Or let's say you want to store measurements like 5.2m, integers are not useful, and here `floats` are used, to keeps the parts after decimal.

For you other two questions, you should probably state the language you are talking about

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to really answer without knowing what language you are using, but in general:

- A string would store letters, numbers, punctuation, etc., such as `"Junied Munshi!"`
- An integer would store whole numbers such as `666`. The exact range would depend on the size of the integer, in some situations you might be looking at -32768 to +32767.
- A float would store a number with a decimal point, such as `1234.5678`. Float numbers typically have a "mantissa" (the digits) and an exponent (where the decimal place is).

---

> what does it do when I add a certain name like string, integers, and float to the line of code

You need to give more information about what language you are talking about, but those names are probably being used to define (create) a variable of that type.

Answer (score 0):

Good question! strings are a good way to store words, for instance:

```
name = "Jeremy"
print(name)
```

integers are used when we don't need decimal places, for instance:

```
n = 100
for i in range(n):
    print(i)
```

floats are going to be used when we are doing calculations that require precision, for instance:

```
a = 15
b = 2
#c is the float variable in this example
c = a/b
print(c)
```

im not fully sure what you mean by the second part of your question. For the third part when we put a variable type in our line of code we are telling the computer what the data is, for some programming languages they will automatically figure out the data type for you, but in a language like C++ you need to declare variable types.